# Modify class method arguments

Tags: javascript, class, prototype

I am using two different libraries.

The first one provides the following class:

```
class VolumeLoader {
    load(string: string): Promise<any> // Returns a promise to attach callbacks
    // rest of methods
}
```

The second one is using the previous loader like this

```js
const loader = new Loader()
loader.load(string, callback) // Provides an argument to attach callback (without promises)
```

**How can I modify `VolumeLoader` so it can accept `string, callback`?**

**I CAN NOT MODIFY ORIGINAL CLASS**

What I've tried:

```js
// Creating a new class using the previous loader. The load function works but I lose the rest of methods.
class _VolumeLoader {
    loader = new VolumeLoader
    load (string, callback) {
        this.loader.load(string).then(callback)
    }
    // rest of methods are lost! :(
}
```

```js
// Modifying directly the prototype
const OriginalVolumeLoader = VolumeLoader;
const _VolumeLoader = VolumeLoader

_VolumeLoader.prototype.load = function (string, callback) {
    OriginalVolumeLoader.prototype.load.call(this, string).then(callback)
}
// Creates an infinite loop, not sure why :(
```

None worked :(

Comment: @CertainPerformance Added :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the original `load` method *alone* to avoid the infinite loop. Doing `OriginalVolumeLoader = VolumeLoader` will only create another reference to the same `class` in memory, so changes to the `OriginalVolumeLoader` end up as changes to `VolumeLoader` too.

Use:

```
const origLoad = VolumeLoader.prototype.load;
VolumeLoader.prototype.load = function (string, callback) {
    origLoad.call(this, string).then(callback)
};
```

Comment: Almost got it! Wonderful, its working now. Thank you! :)